# ASP.NET MVC Form BeginCollectionItem - use EditorFor instead of Partial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I made an EditorFor Template for an object which has multiple collections, and collections within collections.  I had to make it so I could delete and add items to the list of collections, and still have model validation work.

Initially I had all my Form fields using EditorFor Razor Methods.

Main Form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditEvent", null, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod =    "Post" }, new { @id = "valEditEvent", @class = "valEditEvent" }))
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rooms.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rooms[i], "RoomEditVm")
}
```

Room Editor Template View

```
@model Ltd.Event.Room
<tr class="roomRow">
    <td>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.RoomName, new { @class = "RoomNameBox" })
    </td>
    <td class="deleteContainer">
        <img class="deleteRoom Right" src="@Url.Content("~/img/close.png")" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><span>Click To Add Another Room</td>
</tr>
```

Because I was already a few collections deep, keeping track of the index of each collection in the form was bug prone, so I used Steve Sanderson's BeginCollectionItem to assign a Guid to each collection item.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem
** this is a good tutorial

http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/

The sample use it as a Partial. ie.

Main

```
@foreach(Ltd.Event.Room rm in this.Event.Rooms)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("RoomPartialVm", rm);
}
```

Room Editor Partial View

```
@model Ltd.Event.Room
<tr class="roomRow">
  @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + ".Rooms"))
    {
      <td>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.RoomName, new { @class = "RoomNameBox" })
      </td>
      <td class="deleteContainer">
          <img class="deleteRoom Right" src="@Url.Content("~/img/close.png")" />
      </td>
  }
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><span>Click To Add Another Room</td>
</tr>
```

This was required to get the `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix` to use to prefix the name of the Nested Collection of form fields.  EditorFor didn't quite do this correctly.

What was desirable about using EditorFor Templates is separating out the Views into a separate folder.  Is there some way that I can use these partials as EditorFor templates.

Comment: Are you dynamically adding and deleting items to your collection using javascript/jquery? Your usage of `EditorFor()` inside a loop and specifying a template name is not correct and never would have worked.

Comment: Well I used UIHint as well.  I also named it the same name as the collection item model.  I use Ajax to call an action method which return a new Partial with a new GUID.

Comment: If your `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Room` is `.../Room.cshtml` then that's correct, and you don't specify the name in the `EditorFor()` method. But you do not use a loop. Its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Rooms)`. The `EditorFor()` method has an overload that accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and generates the correct html for items in a collection including any prefix and the indexer.

Comment: Yes so I create a View for List<Room> but if I need to add a new Item to this collection.  I have an action method which would return the EditorTemplate and would need to know the prefix....

Comment: My comments were relating to your initial `EditorTemplate` usage. If you need to dynamically add and delete items, then `BeginCollectionItem()` is a good approach, but it uses a partial and is not the same as an `EditorTemplate`. Having to pass the prefix around for nested collections is a pain but necessary.

Comment: Yeah thanks.  I suppose it is best as a Partial, since I do use JQuery to call an Action Method to add a new item.  I just really wanted a way to separate out these views from the rest.  Maybe there was a way to put the  Partial inside an EditorFor